# Debugging: LATERAL query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, debugging

```
SELECT
cu.user_id,
cu.gender,
CASE WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = cu.gender THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 
sexual_orientation,
os_name,
ROUND((DATE(NOW()) - cu.birthdate)/365.25) AS user_age,
SUM(dsb.likes) AS likes,
SUM(dsb.dislikes) AS dislikes,
SUM(dsb.blocks) AS blocks,
SUM(dsb.matches) AS matches,
SUM(dsb.received_likes) AS received_likes,
SUM(dsb.received_dislikes) AS received_dislikes,
SUM(dsb.received_blocks) AS received_blocks,
CASE WHEN cu.status = 'default' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS recall_case,
CASE WHEN cu.status = 'default' THEN extract(epoch from 
cu.last_activity - cu.updated_time)/86400 ELSE 0 END AS 
recall_retention
FROM ( SELECT stats.core_users cu
LEFT JOIN yay.daily_swipes_by_users dsb ON (dsb.user_id = cu.user_id)
WHERE cu.user_id = '1' GROUP BY 1) e1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT cd.os_name FROM stats.core_devices cd WHERE 
e1.user_id = cd.user_id ORDER BY cd.updated_time DESC LIMIT 1) e2
ON TRUE;
```

Current Error Code:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT"
LINE 18: LEFT JOIN yay.daily_swipes_by_users dsb ON (dsb.user_id = cu...
         ^

Comment: that is an incomplete query... no group by... no alias dsb info and you refer to many columns from cu that are not in the select clause of that subquery

Answer (score 0):

The supplied query would fail in many ways, the following might work I hope, but as you can see this drops a great deal of other columns in the process

```
SELECT
   e1.user_id
 , e1.cu
 , e2.os_name
FROM (
       SELECT stats.core_users cu, cu.user_id
       LEFT JOIN yay.daily_swipes_by_users dsb ON (dsb.user_id = cu.user_id)
       WHERE cu.user_id = '1'
       GROUP BY stats.core_users cu, cu.user_id
       ) e1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(
      SELECT cd.os_name 
      FROM stats.core_devices cd 
      WHERE e1.user_id = cd.user_id 
      ORDER BY cd.updated_time DESC 
      LIMIT 1) e2 ON TRUE
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  cu.user_id,
  cu.gender,
  CASE WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = cu.gender THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sexual_orientation,
  e2.os_name,
  ROUND((DATE(NOW()) - cu.birthdate)/365.25) AS user_age,
  CASE WHEN cu.status = 'default' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS recall_case,
  CASE WHEN cu.status = 'default' THEN extract(epoch from cu.last_activity - cu.updated_time)/86400 ELSE 0 END AS recall_retention,
  SUM(dsb.likes) AS likes,
  SUM(dsb.dislikes) AS dislikes,
  SUM(dsb.blocks) AS blocks,
  SUM(dsb.matches) AS matches,
  SUM(dsb.received_likes) AS received_likes,
  SUM(dsb.received_dislikes) AS received_dislikes,
  SUM(dsb.received_blocks) AS received_blocks
FROM
  stats.core_users cu
LEFT JOIN yay.daily_swipes_by_users dsb ON (dsb.user_id = cu.user_id)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT cd.os_name FROM stats.core_devices cd WHERE cu.user_id = cd.user_id ORDER BY cd.updated_time DESC LIMIT 1) e2
ON TRUE
WHERE cu.user_id = '1'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
;
```

This works.